# Getting FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT":"false" in ios titanium

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, titanium, runtime-error

here is my code to like a facebook page I am getting the alert ('you liked the APP on facebook') but the no of likes does not increase and the log states "FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT:false"

```
    like.addEventListener('click', function() {
 var data = {
    access_token :Ti.Facebook.accessToken,
    object:'link'
};fb.reauthorize(['read_stream'], "me", function(e){

if (e.success == true){

   Titanium.Facebook.requestWithGraphPath('link', data, 'POST', function(e) {
    if (e.success) {
        alert('You liked The APP on Facebook!');
        Ti.API.log('Success!  From FB: ' + e.result);
    } else {
        if (e.error) {
            alert(e.error);
        } else {
            alert('Unknown result');
        }
 }
 });

}
```

});

if i change
        Titanium.Facebook.requestWithGraphPath('link', data, 'POST',
to
        Titanium.Facebook.requestWithGraphPath('objectID/likes', data, 'POST',

i am getting error "The operation couldn't be completed(com.facebook.sdk error 5.)"

Titanium Studio Version: 3.2.3.201404181442
Titanium SDK: 3.2.3.GA
XCode Version: 5.1.1

Comment: I think you should try with GET method instead of POST.

Comment: @nick thank you so much for your response I am stuck due to this problem from past 2 days and no i was getting no response from any community     FBSession:should only be used from a single thread at app.js i get this when i run the app . and if i again run  i get the error "unknown error"